# Fetch a particular word from an xml using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to fetch a particular word from an xml by using sfk.exe tool. What it is doing is its fetching the whole sentence/line where the word exists instead of just that word. I want to fetch that word and store it in a temp file to be later stored in a variable. 
These words will change, basically its the name of the client and it would vary depending on which client's xml is it.

`sfk find "C:\Env\Test\test.xml" "Name" > %temp%\Test.tmp`

The above line of code fetches the following:
`<Org Updated="date" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4"Database="Test" Client="Name">`

So basically its getting me the whole line whereas i only want to get "Name" without the quotes.

Comment: Are you aware that your `sfk` command is only doing exactly the same as the built in `find` command. `Find /I "Name"<"C:\Env\Test\test.xml">"%TEMP%\Test.tmp"`?

Comment: You already have "Name" ... that's what you searched for.

Comment: @PaulH I have "Name" along with `<Org Updated="date" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4"Database="Test" Client="Name">` I just want Name in my tmp file and nothing else because i want to store the value (Name) in a variable.

Comment: @Compo Yes but i use sfk's other commands too in my script which makes it easier. Coming back to my query, sfk fetches the whole line but i just want the value in the tmp file.

Comment: Are you searching  _literally_ for string `Name`  or for varying string `SomeName` as a particular value of `Client="SomeName"`?

Comment: @JosefZ Its the name of a client and it can vary with clients. Ex: Client = "Microsoft". In another file it could be Client="Google". Since the length varies i do not want to employ a solution which counts the number of words or anything like that. If you know what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

If the line layout doesn't change then you could try this:

```bat
Set "Name=Microsoft"

For /F Tokens^=10^ Delims^=^" %%A in (
'Find /I "%Name%"^<"C:\Env\Test\test.xml"') Do Echo "%%A"
```

As a side note, were you to search for `Client=` you could probably simplify it further:

```bat
For /F Tokens^=10^ Delims^=^" %%A in (
'sfk find "C:\Env\Test\test.xml" "Client="') Do Echo "%%A"
```

I have used both the `Find` and `sfk` commands, they may be interchanged as you see fit.

Comment: This is awesome. Works well. Its fetching the value along with the quotes, how can i remove the quotes within this command itself? Also what if i want to run this in a loop . Ex: Client = "Microsoft" , Client = "Google", Client="Yahoo" . Now if i want to check for these values in the xml and whichever gets fetched in %%A i can compare it if %%A=Microsoft Goto Run-microsoft, if %%A=Google Goto Run-Google etc

Comment: Change `Echo "%%A"` to `Echo %%A` to get rid of your unwanted double quotes.

Comment: Thanks and what if i want to assign the value of %%A to another variable say %Client%?

Comment: how about `set "client=%%A"` ?

Comment: I did try SET Client="%%A" before asking but this didn't work. Will try adding the quotes before client.

Comment: @Compo `For /F Tokens^=10^ Delims^=^" %%A in (
'Find /I "%Name%"^<"C:\Env\Test\test.xml"') Do Echo "%%A"` How can i catch the error and perform a certain action if the xml doesnt consist the attribute and it says no such file or directory found?

Answer (score 1):

Although batch files are not the best choice for processing XML data as they do not support them natively, I want to show you a way to do what you want:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Capture the output of the `find` command (`sfk` command is not necessary):
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    ^< "C:\Env\Test\test.xml" find /I " Client="
') do (
    rem // Store found line in variable:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Remove everything up to and including the first occurrence of ` Client`
    rem    from the string; then split off the leading `=` and the training `>`;
    rem    finally, remove the surrounding `""` from the remaining string: */
    for /F "delims==>" %%I in ("!LINE:* Client=!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Return the extracted string:
        echo(%%~I
    )
)
```

This works only when there is a single occurrence of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `Client` in each applicable line, followed by an `=`-sign. Furthermore, this `Client=` attribute must be the last one in the containing tag, hence the whole attribute definition `Client="Name"` must be immediately followed by `>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks good. How can i use this loop to dynamically check for a list of client names in the xml and compare the fetched value (%%I) like this. If %%I=Microsoft goto run-microsoft,  If %%I=Google goto run-Google

Comment: You're welcome! you can hard-code the list of client names in the batch file, like `if /I "%%~I"=="Microsoft" goto ...` and so on, instead of the `echo(%%~I` command, or, if the list is in another text file, nest another `for /F` loop that reads from that text file; if you have trouble, I recommend to post a new question...

Comment: Is there a way to look for the keyword in .xml file located in multiple locations within the same loop and capture the error and perform a certain action if no such keyword is found in any of the locations?

Answer (score 1):

Although Windows batch can be kind of lame handling `xml`, this (quite simple) case could be solved using a (quite simple) script providing additional preliminary assumptions on structure of parsed line(s).

However, the following solution lays emphasis on (as far as possible) universal approach with no premises on position of `Client=` attribute inside the containing tag, or its unicity (singularity) inside a line, or number of preceding `"` double quotes etc. etc.:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
      findstr /i /r "\<Client=" "D:\bat\SO\files\q44533501_input.xml"
  ') do (
    rem ECHO=merely debugging output 
        ECHO %%G
    set "_line=%%~G"
    call :lineFound
)
goto :eof

:lineFound
  rem remove cmd-poisonous characters `<` and `>` (replace them with spaces)
  set "_line=%_line:<= %"
  set "_line=%_line:>= %"

  set "_takeNextItem="
  rem parse 
  for %%g in ( %_line% ) do (
    if defined _takeNextItem (
      set "_takeNextItem="
      set "_client=%%~g"
      call :clientSet
    ) else (
      if /I "%%~g" == "Client" set "_takeNextItem=%%~g"
    )
  )
goto :eof

:clientSet
  rem ECHO=merely debugging output;
  rem      handle %_client% variable in desired manner instead 
      ECHO(%_client%
goto :eof
```

Of course, you could use `sfk find "C:\Env\Test\test.xml" "Client="` command instead of my `findstr /i /r "\<Client=" "D:\bat\SO\files\q44533501_input.xml"` at the 4th line.

**Sample output** (includes debugging `ECHO %%G` to show possible variability of input `xml` file):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\q44533501.bat
<Org Updated="date" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4" Database="Test" Client="Name">
Name
<Org Updated="date" Database="Test" Client="Name2" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4">
Name2
<Org Updated="yesterday" Client="Name3"></Org><Org Client="Name4" Updated="today">
Name3
Name4

==>
```

**Edit**. To explain the `:lineFound` section, let's take look at [`FOR` command](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) (it is mostly used to process files, but you can also process *text strings*):

> ```
> Conditionally perform a command on several files.
>
> Syntax
>       FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command
>
> Key
>    set         : A set of one or more files, separated by any standard delimiter.
>                  Wildcards can be used.
>
>    command     : The command to carry out, including any command-line parameters.
>
>    %%parameter : A replaceable parameter: e.g. in a batch file use %%G 
>                                                (on the command line %G)
> ```

and utilise the fact that a `xml` line we want to parse contains just **standard delimiters** mentioned above in `set` description, see [Delimiters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters):

> Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the
>   command line up into words.
>
> Parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the
>   following are also valid delimiters:
>
> - Comma (,)
> - Semicolon (;)
> - Equals (=)
> - Space ( )
> - Tab (     )

Some example might help: `for %g in ( %_line% ) do …` loop processes, *item by item*, the `_line` variable after splitting it using *standard delimiters* as item separators. In principle, we obtain a sequence where each attribute name is followed by attribute value (but tag name as the first item):

```
==> for %g in ( %_line% ) do @echo %g
Org
Updated
"date"
Database
"Test"
Client
"Name2"
Owner
"Test"
Version
"2/1/3/4"

==>
```

Note that `_line` variable is hard-coded, for this particular sample case, as

```
==> set "_line=<Org Updated="date" Database="Test" Client="Name2" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4">"

==> set "_line=%_line:<= %"

==> set "_line=%_line:>= %"

==> set _line
_line= Org Updated="date" Database="Test" Client="Name2" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4"
```

Comment: Thats really good, thanks but to be honest my knowledge of batch scripting is pretty basic and a major portion of your script has gone over my head. Could you please explain the :lineFound section?